# limit of f(x)/x, where f'(x)->0

Tags: calculus

Say $f:[0,\infty) \to \Bbb R$ is differentiable.

Given $\lim_{x \to \infty}f'(x) = 0$, I need to prove that $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)/x = 0$.

I tried looking here and using the Lagrange's mean value theorm, without any success (wrong use of the theorm I suppose)
Any ideas?

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Since we are given that $\lim_{x\to 0}f'(x)=0$, we have by L'Hopital's rule that

$$
\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}=\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{f'(x)}{1}=0\,.
$$

Comment: In the case that $\lim_{ x\to \infty} f(x)$ fails to be $\infty$, this application of L'Hospital is incorrect. For instance, L'Hospital does not apply to $f(x) = x \sin(x)$

Comment: @BenGrossmann No, we don't need to assume anything about the limit of $f$, not even it's existence.

Comment: @bengrossman Your assertion is incorrect.  See the penultimate paragraph of "General Proof" section of the article [HERE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule#General_proof).  Note that if $g\to \infty$ and the limit of $f'/g'$ exists, then the limit of $f$ can be anything (or even nonexistent) for LHR to apply.

Comment: @MarkViola This is a great source as well: https://www.math.ksu.edu/~nagy/snippets/stolz-cesaro.pdf But in a nutshell, we use Stolz-Cesaro Theorem and the Mean Value Theorem, and the indetermine form requirement comes from the Stolz-Cesaro Theorem, which requires only the denominator to diverge to $+\infty$. The other cases are consequences of this.

Comment: @MarkViola At the very least, the version of L'Hospital's rule [(from the page you linked)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule#General_form) stipulates that limits of the absolute values of the numerator and denominator are either both infinite or both zero. It's interesting that the trick applies under weaker constraints but I think that falls beyond the domain of what is usually referred to as L'Hospital's rule.

Comment: @MarkViola Anyway, thanks for teaching me something new!

Comment: @Botond Interesting, thanks for pointing that out. As I say in my other comment, I still think that this technically is outside the purview of "L'Hospital's rule".

Comment: @BenGrossmann I totally agree, it's not commonly known. It might be because it's not as useful as the other cases, but it's interesting at least from a theoretical point of view.

Comment: @BenGrossmann You're welcome.  My pleasure.  Note that the condition $\lim |f|=\infty$ is never used in the proof.  And in fact, the limit need not even exist.  Read the penultimate paragraph.

Comment: @MarkViola I think you might have misread my response. I understand now, but I think that the more general result lies beyond the purview of "L'Hospital's rule".

Comment: Well, LHR still applies.  So, I don't understand your point.  There might be situations for which the limit of $f$ may be difficult to evaluate, but $g\to \infty$ and we can compute relatively easily the limit $\lim \frac{f'}{g'}$, from which LHR gives the limit $\lim \frac fg$.

Comment: @MarkViola My point is that L'HR refers to a result with specific assumption, so replacing $\lim \frac fg$ with $\lim \frac {f'}{g'}$ without the usual $0/0$ or $\infty/\infty$ condition fulfilled cannot properly be called "L'Hospital's rule". Analogously, the alternating series test tells you that $\sum a_n b_n$ converges when $a_n \to 0$ monotonically and $b_n =(-1)^n$. This can be extended to the case that the partial sums $\sum_{n = 1}^N b_n$ are bounded, so perhaps one could say that $\sum_n \sin(n)/n$ converges "by the alternating series test" since we have applied the same conclusion...

Comment: @Mark ...to a slightly different situation. However, we don't call this "the alternating series test"; we call it Dirichlet's test. It is a *generalization* of the alternating series test in the same way that going from $f/g$ to $f'/g'$ is a generalization of LHR.

Comment: @BenGrossmann   Yes, Dirichelt's test certainly includes Leibniz's test as a special case.  But I don't see the analogy with LHR in the cases for which $f\to \infty$ and $f$ does not go to infinity.  The assumptions of LHR for the case in which $g\to \infty$ do not require $f\to \infty$.  It is not a generalization at all.  The assumption that $f\to \infty$ is just simply not required.  So there is no special case.

Answer (score 2):

The mean value theorem is certainly a valid approach.

Let $f$ be such that $\lim_{x \to \infty}f'(x) = 0$. Let $\epsilon > 0$. Let $x_0$ be such that for all $x > x_0$, we have $|f'(x)| < \epsilon/2$. Let $x_1$ be such that $x_1 > \max\{|2f(x_0)|/\epsilon,x_0\}$. Consider any $x$ with $x > x_1$. By the mean value theorem, there exists a value $c \in (x_0,x)$ such that $f'(c) = (f(x) - f(x_0))/(x - x_0)$.
$$
\begin{align}
\left|\frac{f(x)}{x} \right| &\leq \frac{|f(x_0)|}{x} + \frac{|f(x) - f(x_0)|}{x}
\\ & \leq \frac{|f(x_0)|}{x_1} + \frac{|f'(c)| \cdot (x - x_0)}{x}
\\ & < \frac{|f(x_0)|}{2|f(x_0)|/\epsilon} + \frac{|f'(c)| \cdot (x - x_0)}{x- x_0}
 < \epsilon/2 + \epsilon/2 = \epsilon.
\end{align}
$$
That is, for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an $x_1 > 0$ such that $|f(x)/x| < \epsilon$ whenever $x > x_1$. The conclusion follows.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: for a solution that doesn't use L'Hopital's rule, note that for all $\varepsilon>0$, you can find $M\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $$f'(x)<\varepsilon \quad \forall x>M.$$

You can use this with the mean value theorem to give a bound to $|f(x)|$ in terms of $x$ for all $x$ large enough. $\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}=0$ will follow from this.